# picturefill.js issue with z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm using picturefill to do responsive images.  The issue that I am having is that I am calling picturefill(); method on the success callback of an ajax call.  When the dynamically loads, picturefill is called.

This works fine but the issue is that the picturefill'd picture covers up all of the elements that are overlayed on top of it for about 1 second.  this causes an uncomfortable effect because the overlayed elements shows up abruptly. so the sequence is that we see the elements, elements dissapear, and then elements reappear from under the picturefill'd picture.

has anyone else run into this problem and does anyone have any suggestions on how I can deal with it? I already tried changing the z-index of the picture fill'd pictures to z-index:1 and everything else to z-index: 200 but still no luck.

Adding some code:

```
  <!-- Begin centerimage Container -->
```

```
            <!-- Begin rightcaption -->
          <div class="rightcaption">

        OVERLAID CAPTION

          </div>
          <!-- End rightcaption -->   

<!-- Begin flip-container -->
<div class= "flip-container">
        <div class= "flipper">
            <div class= "front">
          <div class="main-pic-wrap" id="bloop">

          <div data-picture data-alt="name" data-class="relative_image">
            <div data-src=source> </div> 
            <div data-src=img2%> data-media="(min-width: 480px)"></div>
            <div data-src=img3%> data-media="(min-width: 767px)"></div>

            <!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
            <div data-src="medium.jpg"></div>
            <![endif]-->

            <!-- Fallback content for non-JS browsers. Same img src as the initial, unqualified source element. -->
            <noscript>
                <img src=img3 alt="Image of Activity">
            </noscript>
          </div>
          </div>



            </div>
            <div class = "back">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    <!-- End flipper -->
    </div>
    <!-- End flip-container container -->



<div id="moreShowHideGroup">
    <div id="mapShowHide" class="icon-globe"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without seeing any code or example it's really hard to help, but my guess is probably that the picture is `position: fixed` or the like during its animation

Comment: hmm not sure how I would switch the position:fixed during the animation. but I added the HTML code that I have.

Comment: Can't really help with this code. Create a jsfiddle or give a link to live example.

Comment: hmm...really difficult for me to recreate it since I am loading AJAX content and then using a success callback to call picturefill.  I tried to recreate it here but the picturefill and overlaid content is showing up at the same time without a delay so hard to tell if picturefill'd image is covering teh overlaid content at runtime.  http://jsfiddle.net/hungkienluu/ceM6A/

Answer (score 0):

Alright - finally figured it out.  So I believe what is happening is that the container which is holding my picture fill'd picture and my position:absolute floating element is losing it's width property on execution of picturefill since I think picturefill.js removes the picturefill div from the DOM and then replaces it.

While it's removed, the container element which I have set to width:100% has nothing inside to give it an actual width so it collapses for a split-second and my fixed position elements dissapear for a split second.

To prevent this, I put another position:absolute div with 100% width into the container and then dropped my other position:absolute divs into this new container.  So the structure looks like this:

```
    <div class="main" style="position:relative"> 
      <div data-picture data-alt="name">div data-src=source> </div></div>
      <div class="always-here" style="position:absolute" top:0; left:0;>
        <div class="fixed" style="position:absolute; top:2%; left:2%; ">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```